# Помогите определить шрифт

Tags: графика, шрифты

[image]

Ребята , подскажите пожалуйста что за шрифт.

Comment: https://capyba.ru/services/fontfinder/ - сервис автоматического определения всех шрифтов на странице по ссылке

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не по теме.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как определить шрифт по картинке ?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/876012/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%88%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

courier bold ?

Comment: Хотя нет  "А" "Й"  не подходят.  а цифры в точку

Comment: посмотрите вариации на тему Courier Bold, Courier New, Classic и подобные