# Как определить шрифт по картинке ?

Tags: изображения, шрифты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Как определить шрифт который использовался для создания изображения на сайте? Нужно создать еще несколько картинок этого же стиля а связи с создателем предыдущих изображений нет. Пробовал прогонять через разные сервисы но безрезультатно. Кто-то что-то посоветует ?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что Stack Overflow не про дизайн/шрифты

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, здсь не бюро подбора шрифтов.

Answer (score 1):

Существует множество сайтов, которые предлагают подобную услугу: загружаешь картинку, обводишь текст - и подбирается наиболее подходящий шрифт.

Вот несколько примеров навскидку:

- Cервис What The Font: http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/
- http://www.bowfinprintworks.com/SerifGuide/serifsearch.php
- ответы людей:  http://www.typophile.com/forum/29

Остальные просто нагуглить по словам типа "сервисы определения шрифта по картинке".

Некоторые сервисы умеют русские шрифты, но обычно коряво.

Comment: Да я в курсе об этих сервисах. Но я прогнал через штук 10-ть и не один не определил релевантно. Более того - никто из них не был даже рядом с ответом. Шрифт то я уже нашел и вопрос состоит скорее не в том чтобы мне нашли шрифт ( как любезно писали выше ), а в том что как оказалось при возникновении подобной ситуации - нет действительно толкового ресурса. П.С. спасибо А К за помощь.